# Replace Proxy Credentials with sed

Tags: regex, sed, substitution

I try to replace this samples:

```
http_proxy="http://QQ@127.0.0.1:8080/"
http://test1:test2@127.0.0.1:8080/
http_proxy="http://QQ@127.0.0.1:8080/
http://@127.0.0.1:8080/"
```

with this regex `(^.+?\/\/).+?(@.*$)`
to get it like this

```
http_proxy="http://user:pass@127.0.0.1:8080/"
http://user:pass@127.0.0.1:8080/
http_proxy="http://user:pass@127.0.0.1:8080/"
http://user:pass@127.0.0.1:8080/
```

According to https://regex101.com/r/AE3Wxi/3 the regex seems to be working for the first 3 lines.

But when i try it with

```
echo http_proxy=\"http://QQ@127.0.0.1:8080/\" | sed  's/\(^.+?\/\/\).+?\(@.*$\)/\1user:pass\2/g'
```

It has this output:

```
http_proxy="http://QQ@127.0.0.1:8080/"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the plus `\+` and sed does not support non greedy quantifiers like `.\+?`

If you also want a match for the last example `http://@127.0.0.1:8080/"` the quantifier after the double forward slash should be `*` instead of `+`

You could write the command as:

```
echo http_proxy=\"http://QQ@127.0.0.1:8080/\" | sed  's/\(^.\+\/\/\).*\(@.*$\)/\1user:pass\2/'
```

Output

```
http_proxy="http://user:pass@127.0.0.1:8080/"
```

If you only want to replace the first occurrence in the line, you might shorten it to

```
echo http_proxy=\"http://QQ@127.0.0.1:8080/\" | sed  's~\(//\)[^@]*\(@\)~\1user:pass\2~'
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7g6AG8/1) and [here](https://regex101.com/r/nQyxCK/1) for the captured group values.

Comment: Your first command is working perfect for the first 3 examples.

Do you know what needs to be modified to also work with `http://@127.0.0.1:8080/"`

Comment: @marcohald I have updated the answer for that scenario by using an asterix `*`